# Small discrepancy in scale reported by OpenLayers and GeoServer (after DPI fix)

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, scale

I'm implementing some scale-dependent functionality in an application that uses OpenLayers 2.12 on the client and GeoServer 2.6.1 on the server.

The legend is created in JavaScript and when a scale-dependent rule in the SLD is disabled by its MaxScaleDenominator element I want to show this in the legend by changing CSS attributes.

The client responds to 'zoomend' events by querying the current scale, looking for any legend items whose rendering rules will be disabled at this scale, and visually identifying those as disabled (e.g. grey text, disabled checkbox).

At first I was seeing significant discrepancies between OpenLayers and GeoServer about what the scale was, but this was resolved by setting the `OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH property` to `90.71428571428571`.

This change addressed the bulk of the issue but I still see a small discrepancy that seems proportional to the scale, e.g.

```
OpenLayers: 68571.4656
GeoServer: 68609.7366320815

OpenLayers: 1097143.4496
GeoServer: 1097755.7861133264
```

Now for the important part (I think)... The client displays data in what OpenLayers calls EPSG:900913 (3857) but it is stored in the database in 4326. I'm currently working on the assumption that the discrepancy in reported scale is due to this difference.

1. Is it reasonable to assume that the discrepancy is due to the projection being performed by GeoServer?
2. Should I expect this discrepancy to be more pronounced towards the poles?

Comment: Do these scale issues also evidence themselves on the GeoServer built-in OpenLayers viewer? That has a scale factor at the bottom, so it should be fairly simple to compare. I wouldn't have thought the reprojection was the cause, well, not unless it's the way it's defined in OpenLayers; that can be rather finicky in my experience.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan good question, yes the OpenLayers previewer does also present the same discrepancy (its DPI is set the same as mine)

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure where the issue lies then; GeoServer or OpenLayers. So the data's native projection is 4326; what format are you asking GeoServer serving it in; 4326 or 3857?

Comment: Yes, data is stored in 4326. As OpenLayers is configured to display in 900913 the WMS requests ask GeoServer for the data in 900913 - GeoServer is doing the projection.

Comment: I suppose you can debug it the "hard" way. View the WMS image itself and get its properties. Use the pixel width and height as well as knowing the DPI to calculate the *actual* scale of the image. See which one it agrees with, OpenLayers or GeoServer. For the maths, second answer here - bottom equation - https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/1069/how-to-calculate-the-size-of-a-map-tile-on-the-ground